# Create a dictionary from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following code

```
pd.DataFrame(index=["A", "A", "B","B","B"], columns=["col1","col2","col3"],
data=np.array([[5,3,5],[8,6,4],[8,6,4],[2,7,6],[8,6,4]]))
```

which results in the following dataframe

```
    col1    col2    col3
A      5     3       5
A      8     6       4
B      8     6       4
B      2     7       6
B      8     6       4
```

I want to create a dictionary out of it with keys A and B and values to be dataframes with the rest of the data. For example for A the value should be a dataframe like below.

```
col1    col2    col3
5        3       5
8        6       4
```

Comment: Martin, you want a dict that you can rebuild back into A or B?   pd.DataFrame(df.T['A'].apply(list).T.to_dict(orient='records'))  will give you an A, but to rebuild it you have to do: pd.DataFrame(df.T['A'].apply(list).T.to_dict(orient='records'), index=['A', 'A'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with `groupby` and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default index:

```
d = {k:v.reset_index(drop=True) for k, v in df.groupby(level=0)}
print (d)
{'A':    col1  col2  col3
0     5     3     5
1     8     6     4, 'B':    col1  col2  col3
0     8     6     4
1     2     7     6
2     8     6     4}
```

---

```
print (d['A'])
   col1  col2  col3
0     5     3     5
1     8     6     4
```

If index values is necessary not changed is possible use:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(level=0)))
print (d['A'])
   col1  col2  col3
A     5     3     5
A     8     6     4
```

But it is same like selecting original data with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc['A'])
   col1  col2  col3
A     5     3     5
A     8     6     4
```

---

**Setup**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["A", "A", "B","B","B"], 
                  columns=["col1","col2","col3"],
                  data=np.array([[5,3,5],[8,6,4],[8,6,4],[2,7,6],[8,6,4]]))
```